# Performance of list concatenation followed by scanning

Tags: haskell, list

Consider the following code snippet:

```
-- list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
-- list_2 = [4, 5, 6] 
final_list =  list_1 ++ list_2
result = map (+1) final_list
```

Is the time spent by it proportional just to the length of `final_list`, and the price of list concatenation is not paid?

My idea is that concatenation is done lazily; to quote the source of GHC Base.hs,

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(++) []     ys = ys
(++) (x:xs) ys = x : xs ++ ys
```

Since `map` constantly chips away the head of the list, I suppose that the concatenation as done by the recursive call in the last line is always done in lockstep with the `map` execution, so `list_1` is effectively scanned only once.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct.  It's easy to test your theory by making `list_2` infinite:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = repeat 4
final_list = list_1 ++ list_2
result = map (+1) final_list

print $ take 10 result
-- Outputs [2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
```

Congratulations!  You just ran an infinite loop in a few microseconds! (Not really).